# Open webpages in iframe with different IP?

Tags: php, iframe, proxy, load, ip

I need to open many webpages in continuous timely interval, but each time with different IP.

I am having list of many like...
183.89.108.17:3128
78.93.73.182:8080
218.92.252.21:8080

These are proxies with port numbers. How can I create a script that loads my hundreds of webpages with two minutes interval and each time choosing different IPs provided by me.

Is there any class for this? I am using PHP scripting to do so.

Comment: I'm sure you'll find someone who is willing to write such a script. Just hire someone.

Answer (score 0):

This is a neat idea, but you'll have to use javascript to get there. I can see this being useful for keeping tabs on a bunch of websites. This will get you part of the way there, I've set it to load a new page every 10 seconds. There are probably more elegant ways to do this, but this will work:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>

<iframe id="myiframe" src="http://bing.com" width="800" height="500"></iframe>

<script>
var myAddresses = [
        "http://bing.com"
    ,"http://cnn.com"
    ,"http://mxplx.com"
    ,"http://ideonexus.com"
]

function loadNewSite(loc, i) {
    document.getElementById("myiframe").src = loc;
    i = (i < (myAddresses.length-1)) ? (i+1) : 0;
    setTimeout(function(){nextAddress(i)},10000);
}

function nextAddress(i) {
        loadNewSite(myAddresses[i], i);
}

window.onload(nextAddress(0));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need to open all pages with new proxy. I am having the list of IP:Port so how to use those while opening pages?